# "около [скольких-то]"

Tags: грамматика

Есть ли нормативная форма для выражений с "около" в косвенных падежах? Типа
***"Это грозит увольнением около двум миллионам человек".***

С "примерно" таких вопросов не возникает.

Comment: Мне режет слух, поэтому я и скажу тогда *примерно.*

Comment: Не поверил бы в существование такой нормы: "около" можно отнести к числу (как и к существительному), находящемуся только в родительном падеже.

Comment: @Alex_ander,  это все понятно, что слух режет.  Вопрос в том, ессть ли норма вообще с "около". *Не хватает около двух миллионов* - это нормально?

Comment: @Артём Луговой,  это все понятно, что слух режет. Вопрос в том, ессть ли норма вообще с "около". Не хватает около двух миллионов - это нормально?

Comment: Не уверен я, нормально это или нет, но не удивлюсь, если это нормально. Сам бы сказал: *не хватает где-то или примерно двух миллионов.*

Comment: @behemothus Не хватает около двух миллионов чего-то (либо "имеется недостача чего-то в количестве около двух миллионов") - нормально, поскольку требуется согласование самого "около" по падежу с цифрой, и оно есть (падеж - родительный: около какого числа, скольки?). Если же общий падеж сочетания "число + единица измерения (человек)" отличается от родительного (в исходном примере он дательный: грозит кому?), то он расходится с фиксированным падежом после встраиваемого "около", и выходит, что так сказать нельзя.

Comment: *около какого числа, скольки?* - ну если "скольки", то вы меня сильно утешили.))) Тогда и "не хватает *окол**а*** двух*",   увольнение грозит "*окол**у** двух миллионов*". ))) Ладно, я понял. Вы берете правило по формальному согласованию. А в винительном как прикажете согласовывать? Там-то винительный трубется: "вижу что? - около батальона солдат". Никаких проблем, форма родительного прекрасно работает, заменяя винительный. Так чем дательный хуже?

Answer (score 2):

***Допустимо: *"Это грозит увольнением около двух миллионов человек"*.*** Но только при условии, что выражением "около двух миллионов человек" управляет  отглагольное  существительное *увольнением.* ***Увольнением (кого? чего) около двух миллионов человек.***

Если же словосочетание "около двух миллионов чемовек" поставить в зависимость от глагола грозит ( грозит кому? чему?), то тогда употребление предлога ***около***, требующего исключительно родительного падежа,  недопустимо. Почему? Глаголу ***грозит*** требуется дополнение в дательном падеже (в этом примере), а цельное словосочетание  *числительное + существительное*  при наличии предлога ***около*** поставить в дательный падеж просто невозможно.